# Converting current project into Cucumber

Tags: selenium, testing, eclipse-plugin, cucumber, testng

We already have a working project in test NG and now we are trying to add cucumber framework to it.

Sofar, I could goto eclipse marketplace and download the cucumber plugin, also added cucumber dependencies into my gradle file.

Then I have created a feature file - login.feature and its corresponding step definition for it. In the same feature file I have right clicked -> run as -> (selected) cucumber feature, now the issue is eclipse is unable to recognize the step definition for its corresponding feature file and the executed console in the attached screenshots.

**Output:**
0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.567s

Please see the attached screenshots for more information.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to see whether feature file is running, first you need to make sure that Cucumber Eclipse Plugin is properly installed, Eclipse needs to be restarted after installation. If you are using TestNG then Cucumber-TestNG and Cucumber-Java dependencies of *same version should be used*. I could see *Cucumber-TestNG* dependency **missing**. You need to exclude JUnit also.

Then in order to run feature file, you first need to configure it, by selecting ***Run Configuration->click Cucumber feature(left panel)->select project->provide Feature file location->Apply and Run***

You can also create a Test Runner which will link Feature file with Step definition and run the test as TestNG test from Runner.

Eg. Test Runner

```
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
 
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/featureFiles", glue = "stepDefinitions")
public class RunTestNGTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
 
}
```